# How to create an overlay effect on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So. The team__bio is hidden by default, when you hover over a particular team image, the bio pops up to the side (i have this part working fine), AND the rest of the images get a dark overlay effect on them (except for the image you are hovering, this is the part I need help with!). I have thought about approaching this two different ways, one by creating an overlay "element" and styling it with CSS so that its only "visible" when you hover over one image (this would be more of an overlay on the whole page, which I don't actually need, I just need the effect on the images).

Or I've thought about trying to accomplish this with JavaScript by maybe looping over the team__member s and onmouseover applying an overlay to all the team__image elements except for the one your mouse is over currently.

Here is my HTML, please show me how you would go about this using my HTML! Thank you so much!!

I can ONLY work with VANILLA JS btw

```
<section class="team">
  <h1 class="team__heading">meet the team</h1>
  <p class="team__para">Bunch of people doing creative things.</p>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">Star stuff harvesting star light globular star cluster citizens of distant epochs extraplanetary a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam Drake Equation, dream of the mind's eye, astonishment sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore
            et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">Are creatures of the cosmos network of wormholes consectetur Cambrian explosion realm of the galaxies Flatland vanquish the impossible with pretty stories for which there's little good evidence cosmic ocean citizens of distant epochs finite
            but unbounded trillion, quasar quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam Orion's sword, vanquish the impossible.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">Billions upon billions tendrils of gossamer clouds, dispassionate extraterrestrial observer consectetur lorem ipsum dolor sit amet a very small stage in a vast cosmic arena, cosmic ocean consectetur and billions upon billions upon billions upon
            billions upon billions upon billions upon billions.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">Drake Equation Vangelis hydrogen atoms Cambrian explosion paroxysm of global death made in the interiors of collapsing stars consectetur adipisicing elit a very small stage in a vast cosmic arena?</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">Drake Equation Vangelis hydrogen atoms Cambrian explosion paroxysm of global death made in the interiors of collapsing stars consectetur adipisicing elit a very small stage in a vast cosmic arena?</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">Encyclopaedia galactica prime number encyclopaedia galactica made in the interiors of collapsing stars, tesseract inconspicuous motes of rock and gas dispassionate extraterrestrial observer cosmos, a still more glorious dawn awaits rogue vastness
            is bearable only through love venture rich in mystery from which we spring the ash of stellar alchemy.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">Encyclopaedia galactica prime number encyclopaedia galactica made in the interiors of collapsing stars, tesseract inconspicuous motes of rock and gas dispassionate extraterrestrial observer cosmos.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">Encyclopaedia galactica prime number encyclopaedia galactica made in the interiors of collapsing stars, tesseract inconspicuous motes of rock and gas dispassionate extraterrestrial observer cosmos.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">The last person we talked to said this would be ready prethink, so upsell but new economy, not enough bandwidth. Blue sky thinking value-added, and first-order optimal strategies or diversify kpis.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">Put your feelers out. Can we take this offline knowledge is power overcome key issues to meet key milestones obviously. Cloud strategy moving the goalposts. Blue sky thinking show pony if you want to motivate these clowns.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <section class="team__member">
        <img class="team__image" src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="name of team member" />
        <div class="team__content">
          <h2 class="team__name">John Smith</h2>
          <p class="team__bio">Put your feelers out. Can we take this offline knowledge is power overcome key issues to meet key milestones obviously. Cloud strategy moving the goalposts. Blue sky thinking show pony if you want to motivate these clowns.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code (including the javascript & CSS) you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: By the looks of it you will definitely need some JavaScript because of the DOM structure - assigning some class to all non-hovered team_members (I would suggest to put the class on "grid_item" as it makes more sense to add it on the last parent). Not so good with vanilla js so will leave it to you or somebody else to provide an answer.

Comment: Can you post the css that goes with it?

Comment: @PaigeMeinke i dont have CSS or JS that does or tries to do what I am trying to accomplish (the "overlay"). The CSS I would post would just be making it pretty and positioning my elements with my grid class.